# What is the correct verb corresponding to the noun "summons"?

Tags: verbs

I have just seen this usage:

> ... you have been summonsed ...

My immediate reaction was one of (let's say) surprise; I would have thought the correct form was:

> ... you have been *summoned* ...

Is there, in fact, a verb "to summons", and, if so, where did it come from?

Comment: Close standard reference: [*summons*, verb, /ˈsəmənz/, 1 : *Serve (someone) with a summons* - he has been *summonsed* to appear in court next month](https://www.google.com/search?q=summons&tbs=dfn:1&qscrl=1 "Google Dictionary")

Comment: The NOAD reports that the verb is _summon_; _summons_ is the noun. If the OP is confused about somebody using _summons_ as a verb, I think the question is acceptable.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I wouldn't say I was *confused* -- **irritated** might be more accurate...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Summons* means, in the OED's definition, ‘to cite before a court or a judge or magistrate; to take out a summons against’ and is first recorded in that sense in 1780. It has a similar etymology to *summon* and was once used as an alternative to it.

Answer (score 4):

If you [summons](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/summons) a person, then someone has

> **served** a summons

on or to them.

When they *serve* ([meaning 11b here)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/serve) the summons, the other person has been *served*...so serve has two senses.

[Summons "authoritative call to be at a certain place for a certain purpose" is late 13c., from O.Fr. sumunse, noun use of fem. pp. of somondre.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=summons&searchmode=none)

Comment: Yes, Jeff, although my feeling is that to say "you have been summonsed" feels like it was said by the same person who might have said "you have been *serviced*"

Comment: I would guess that "you have been served" is a way to avoid having to pronounce "summonsed", though that is the correct past participle. Also, usage may differ by jurisdiction; I am in US. And I wouldn't say "you have been serviced", except to a mare or a piece of equipment :).

Answer (score 4):

*[Summons](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/summons_2)* is a verb meaning to order someone to appear in court, a meaning it shares with [*summon*](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/summon). The past tense would be *summonsed* and *summoned* respectively.

Comment: Do you know when it first appeared? To me, it *feels* like somebody illiterate has subverted the OED...

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: See my answer. The form 'summonsed' is found in Charles Dickens's 'Martin Chuzzlewit': 'When Gamp was summonsed to his long home . . .'

Comment: [Here's a 1767 instance](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5_grAAAAMAAJ&q=%22summonsed%22&dq=%22summonsed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JokgT7L1MtG68gPByoTGBw&redir_esc=y) of the "non-judicial" use of **summonsed**. There are plenty of written instances before 1800 which are clearly in the judicial sense, so it obviously caught on fairly quickly. Non-judicial usages seem to tail off by the mid-1800s. I certainly don't think they're synonyms today.

Comment: oic - well since you've just changed the text to reflect that, I'll re-reverse the vote! I quite agree that whereas today *summonsed* is only really used in the judicial context, *summoned* can be used in all, including that.